# Discrete Mathematics-logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

We let $(A,\geq)$ be an ordered set. We define a relation $\preceq$ on AxA by:
$$(a_1,a_2)\preceq(b_1,b_2) <=>[(a_1\neq b_1) ∧(a_1\leq b_1)]∨ [(a_1=b_1)∧(a_2\leq b_2)]$$
First I have to show that $(a_1,a_2)\preceq(b_1,b_2)$ involve that we have $a_1 \leq b_1$. I think it makes sense but I when I try to prove it formally by the distributive probaties, I don't get a statement, which finally proves that. Can someone help me to proove that?

Comment: I get that $(a_1\neq b_1) ∧(a_1\leq b_1) ->(a_1<b_1)$. The distributive probaties give us $[(a_1< b_1)∨(a_1=b_1)]∧[(a_1< b_1)∨a_2\leq b_2)]$, where we get $(a_1< b_1)∨(a_1=b_1)->(a_1 \leq b_1)$. What to I have to do next?

Answer (score 2):

A "formal proof" must be: assume $(a_1,a_2)\preceq(b_1,b_2)$.

This implies (bi-conditional from left to right):

> $\text { (1)   } [(a_1\neq b_1) ∧ (a_1\leq b_1)] ∨ [(a_1=b_1) ∧ (a_2\leq b_2)]$.

[Proof by Cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) with $(a_1=b_1) \lor \lnot (a_1=b_1)$:

(i) if $(a_1=b_1)$, then by [Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction) we have $(a_1=b_1) \lor (a_1 \lt b_1)$ which is abbreviated as $(a_1 \le b_1)$.

(ii) If $\lnot (a_1=b_1)$, we have $\lnot [(a_1=b_1)∧(a_2\leq b_2)]$. Thus, applying [Disjunctive Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism#Formal_notation) to (1) we have:

> $[(a_1\neq b_1) ∧ (a_1\leq b_1)]$,

from which, by [Simplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination): $(a_1\leq b_1)$.

Thus, in both cases (i) and (ii) we have proved that $(a_1\leq b_1)$ holds.

Comment: You don't need LEM. Just prove by cases: If the relation holds, then either $(a_1\neq b_1)\land\color{blue}{(a_1\leq b_1)}$ or $\color{blue}{(a_1=b_1)}\land(a_2\leq b_2)$.